# How to uninstall Whisper from OpenAI

Tags: terminal

I installed Whisper from Open AI (via Terminal) on my mac just to test it out but I've noticed that I'm losing storage space whenever I'm online I want to uninstall it but I'm not sure how is there any way to remove it from my computer?

Thanks for the advice in advance.

Comment: How exactly did you install it?

Comment: Also, https://github.com/openai/whisper shouldn't create additional data while it is not running. Are you sure that whisper is causing the disk space usage you are seeing?

Comment: @nohillside sorry I'm now just able to reply but this is the guide I used to install it [lablab](https://lablab.ai/t/whisper-tutorial). I'm not sure but its the only thing I've installed, I'm uninstalling it just to make sure.

Comment: Ah, it might be still running in jupyther then. Kill the server (or reboot).

Comment: @nollhillside Oh! I didn't realize that it might still be running, thank you!